# How to delete elements from data filtered - Vue.js 2.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Inside the new Vue({}), I use the following code to create two list of students by votes.
How to avoid remove() method duplication to delete one student.

List with number of votes:

```
data: {
    students: 
    [{
        'name': 'Jose',
        'last_name': 'Aris',
        'document': '201700154',
        'campus': 1,
        'votes': 0,
    },

    {
        'name': 'Manuel',
        'last_name': 'Hernadez',
        'document': '201700195',
        'campus': 2,
        'votes': 3,
    },],
},
```

Filters:

```
computed: 
{
    voted: function ()
    {
        return this.students.filter((student) => {
            return student.votes >= 1;
        });
    },

    unvoted: function ()
    {
        return this.students.filter((student) => {
            return student.votes <= 0;
        });
    },
},
```

The problem occurs when two filters have the same index elements:

```
methods: 
{
    remove (student, index)
    {
        if (!confirm(`Are you sure want to delete ${student.name} ${student.last_name}?`))
        {
            return;
        }

        this.students.splice(index, 1);
    },
}
```

Finally, HTML list:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>LIST VOTED</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-for="(student, index) in voted" class="list-group-item">
                {{index}} {{student.name}} {{student.last_name}} / {{student.document}} <vote :student="student" class="pull-right"></vote>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="remove(student, index)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>LIST UNVOTED</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-for="(student, index) in unvoted" class="list-group-item">
                {{index}} {{student.name}} {{student.last_name}} / {{student.document}} <vote :student="student" class="pull-right"></vote>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="remove(student, index)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the index from the filtered lists, you should be using the index from the students list.  Simply do `this.students.splice(this.students.indexOf(student), 1)`

Answer (score 4):

Dont *pass* an index.

```
remove (student)
{
  if (!confirm(`Are you sure want to delete ${student.name} ${student.last_name}?`))
  {
    return;
  }
  const index = this.students.findIndex(s => s === student)
  this.students.splice(index, 1);
},
```

In your template.

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="remove(student)">
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/eRYzRZ?editors=1010).